# Print text and icon link to adjacent posts on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I have the following code in my Wordpress which makes my back/next post navigation:

```
<nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">

<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>' . _x( '', 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( '', 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>'); ?>

...
```

This puts a chevron pointing right and left linked to the back and next posts.

I want the text of the link to show as well as the chevron but not sure how to adjust my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function _x() is for translation in Wordpress waiting as parameters:

> $text (string) (Required) Text to translate.
>
> $context (string)(Required) Context information for the translators.
>
> $domain (string) (Optional) Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated
>   strings. Default value: 'default'

In order to make your text appear just fill the first parameter to set the text you want to show, you will be able to translate it afterwards aswell if you want to. As an example:

```
<nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">

    <?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

        <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>' . _x( get_previous_post()->post_title;, 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
        <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( get_next_post()->post_title;, 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>'); ?>
```

For more information check the official reference for [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) and [next_post_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/).

If you want to get the name of the posts you are linking to, you can do so using [get_next_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) and [get_previous_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) functions.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It's not that I want to put specific text, Each link already has a title just not sure how to show it. Or what part of my code is hiding it

Comment: @user3550879 What do you mean by _showing_?, because to print the value does show it. Just as I mentioned fill the first parameter of the `_x()` function which you have empty `('')`, that should do the trick. Translation is just a plus, but you don't have to use it.

Comment: I apologize, Filling in that area puts text where I want it, but I want that text to be the link's 'title/name/id' or whatever is given to the post by wordpress. The code you put just puts "previous post link' text as written

Comment: @user3550879 you can get that using `get_next_post()->post_title;`. I will update that for you.